# Guardar valores de un form AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, formularios

Tengo este form

```
<form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Add a comment</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="newRole.newAuthor" placeholder="author">
                            <input type="date" ng-model="newRole.newDate">
                            <input type="file" ng-model="newRole.commentImage">
                            <textarea class="form-control metro" ng-model="newRole.newComment"></textarea>
                            <h2>{{txtcomment}}</h2> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- cierre de form para comentario -->

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="trip.makeComment(newRole)">Comment</button>
```

Y quiero guardar los valores aqui dentro:

```
this.tripObject.comments = [
        {
            "author": "Ronnie Oliver",
            "date": "05/06/16 01:19 PM",
            "imageURL": "/assets/images/placeholders/user.svg",
            "text": "Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor."
        },
        {
            "author": "Shaggy Rogers",
            "date": "05/06/16 12:48 PM",
            "imageURL": "/assets/images/placeholders/user.svg",
            "text": "Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor."
        }
    ];
```

Pero algo tengo mal en la función o en el form no se

```
this.makeComment = function(newRole){
                // $scope.txtcomment = '';
                var newRole = {
                    "author":newRole.newAuthor,
                    "date":$scope.newDate,
                    "imageURL":$scope.commentImage,
                    "text" : $scope.newComment
                 }
                console.log($scope.newRole);



                console.log($scope.tripObject.comentario)


                this.tripObject.comments.push($scope.newRole);
                console.log(this.tripObject.comments);



            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, el objeto que tiene los datos es el scope, o en su defecto el que pasas por parámetro. SI te fijas las estas sobreescribiendo la variable que pasa por parámetro, entonces como tampoco es 100% necesaria, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
this.makeComment = function(){
            var newRole = {
                "author":$scope.newRole.newAuthor,
                "date":$scope.newRole.newDate,
                "imageURL":$scope.newRole.commentImage,
                "text" : $scope.newRole.newComment
            }

            this.tripObject.comments.push(newRole);
            console.log(this.tripObject.comments);
        };
```

Otro punto es que yo llamaría los campo exactamente igual a el objeto dentro del array y así me evitaría tener que reprocesarlos en otro objeto.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newRole.author" placeholder="author">
<input type="date" ng-model="newRole.date">
<input type="file" ng-model="newRole.imageURL">
<textarea class="form-control metro" ng-model="newRole.text"></textarea>
```

y luego, sin reprocesar solo:

```
this.makeComment = function(){
     this.tripObject.comments.push($scope.newRole);
}
```